# Apple script : create new Reminder but ALL DAY

Tags: applescript, reminders

I've been searching for several days but couldn't find the answer.

I am trying to create an apple script and generate a **new Reminder** (not event).

I am using the command

```
make new reminder with properties {name:"hii", remind me date:date "Friday 11 November 2016 at 00:00:00"}
```

Which works well.

However, I would like to create all day reminders. In other terms, remove the "time" (this should be possible since in Apple Reminders, you can untick the "time" box).

Can you please help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I found the solution, you simply need to use the parameter :

```
allday due date
```